# Custom F# compiler string checks

Tags: f#

Is it possible to "extend" the F# compiler to do custom compile-time string checks?  I'm thinking of something similar to the checks on `StringFormat` strings when using `sprintf` etc.  When I say "extend", I don't mean build a custom version of the compiler, I mean use existing supported techniques.

Off the top of my head, you might have a `RegexFormat` type.  You provide the regex and the compiler would do the static analysis using the regex.  E.g.

```
//Setup RegexFormat with IP address regex and type abbreviation IpRegexFormat?
//Compile error.  ipAddress expects IpRegexFormat!
let ip = ipAddress "192.168.banana.1"
```

If not, maybe this is a type provider for me :) - If the whole thing is a terrible idea, let me know!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, don't do it. Try and see if type providers do it for you.

Comment: Would love to hear more @RamonSnir.  How and why not!

Comment: I've done several modifications to F# a couple of years ago. While this is very fun, and the result is a better F# - it takes time, Visual Studio doesn't support it, and type providers can do most of the work (disclaimer: I don't like type providers, haven't used them in weeks).

Comment: Ah, I see.  You mean actually modifying the compiler.  I wasn't clear enough in the question.  When I said "extend", I meant via legitimate extension points (i.e. inline types/attributes), not a custom build.

Comment: I see. Then I see no way to do that (except, the thoroughly discussed type providers).

Comment: You would probably want to use the regex type provider or similar.  This would provide an adapter layer into the type  thats consuming it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile-time constraints for strings in F#, similar to Units of Measure - is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417150/compile-time-constraints-for-strings-in-f-similar-to-units-of-measure-is-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have a Regex type provider in Fsharpx.

Here are some [samples](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/tests/FSharpx.TypeProviders.Regex.Tests/Regex.Tests.fs):

```
type PhoneRegex = Regex< @"(?<AreaCode>^\d{3})-(?<PhoneNumber>\d{3}-\d{4}$)">

[<Test>] 
let ``Can call typed IsMatch function``() =      
    PhoneRegex.IsMatch "425-123-2345"
    |> should equal true

[<Test>] 
let ``Can call typed CompleteMatch function``() =      
    PhoneRegex().Match("425-123-2345").CompleteMatch.Value
    |> should equal "425-123-2345"

[<Test>] 
let ``Can return AreaCode in simple phone number``() =
    PhoneRegex().Match("425-123-2345").AreaCode.Value
    |> should equal "425"

[<Test>] 
let ``Can return PhoneNumber property in simple phone number``() =
    PhoneRegex().Match("425-123-2345").PhoneNumber.Value
    |> should equal "123-2345"
```

It's not exactly what you are looking for, but I guess you could easily take this type provider and customize it with your static literal rules.

Comment: Oh yes!  I had forgotten we already have ALL the type providers in FSharpx :)  I may go this way.  The only side issue is that I want to ship this in a tool which is used from fs scripts.  Any idea what the type provider security model does in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure. You have to try it. Might be different in MonoDevelop, Visual Studio or FSI.

Answer (score 1):

I think here the real answer is to use a DU -

```
type ip = 
|IP of byte * byte * byte * byte 
member x.ToString() = 
    match x with
    |IP(a,b,c,d) -> sprintf "%i.%i.%i.%i"
```

Then the compile time check is just

```
let actualip = IP(1uy,1uy,1uy,1uy).ToString()
```

Comment: Blast, IP was a bad example.  DU would work for IP, but not something like "string must be an email address".  I'm interested in a more general solution (or why a more general solution would be bad :).

Comment: @bentayloruk - well you can define a similar DU for email addresses - but for something more general / cleverer you probably need a type provider - particularly if you want compile time checking

Comment: yes, it is the compile time checking I'm after.  I want the sprintf experience for all the strings! :)  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @JohnPalmer how would you define a type for an email address? I mean a real type safe version.

Comment: @forki23 For an email address I would just do `type email = |Email of string * string`.  If you are really worried you could check that neither string has an `@`.  I have actually written a fully automated parser that takes a DU as input and gives an output - you could use this to enforce some rules like no `@` signs - but only at run time.

Comment: You can do a lot runtime checking for email addresses, that's true. But a type provider could try to send an email to the given address and if the server fails then it raises a compile error ;-) Might be a little bit slow, but it's a compelete new world.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to do what the BCL have done with `Uri`, `Guid`, etc and create a type that parses a string input.

I think modifying the compiler, while interesting, is overkill (a "terrible idea," as you say).

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417150/compile-time-constraints-for-strings-in-f-similar-to-units-of-measure-is-it) has been asked before.