# How to generate a bool Member Type via a static member New directly on the Measure type itself?

Tags: types, f#

How would I create a Measure Type in F# that would have a static member New that could be given a value and generate the given Measure Type for a bool?

I have this for int, int64, and decimal, which works perfectly.

```
    [<Measure>] type MyInt = static member New value = value * 1<MyInt>
    [<Measure>] type MyInt64 = static member New value = value * 1L<MyInt64>
    [<Measure>] type MyDecimal = static member New value = value * 1m<MyDecimal>
```

But this doesn't work:

```
    [<Measure>] type MyBool = static member New value = value * true<MyBool>
```

The compile error is `Unexpected token '>' or incomplete expression`

I have also run across this with string, and DateTime.  My goal is to basically use Measure types to provide compile time checking without the run time performance hit of the single case union type wrappers.  ([See this answer by Jack P. for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18815406/24908))

Ideally, I would love to use this concept for all of my types, but I'm not seeing how for types that are not numeric.

Comment: Isn't `LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne` equal to all the `new` functions? - well at least the numerics, haven't tested the bool

Comment: I didn't think of using that.  I will have to check.

Comment: I attempted replacing `1<MyInt>` with `GenericOne`, but that doesn't return an `int<MyInt>` it simply returns `int`.  I attempted replacing `1<MyInt>` with `GenericOne<MyInt>` and get the compiler error `Expected type, not unit-of-measure`

Comment: Also: Multiplication with `1<_>` just to add units can be nicely replaced with something like `LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<MyInt> 17`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, only certain built in types have built in measure type definitions

From the spec these are

```
type float<[<Measure>] 'U>
type float32<[<Measure>] 'U>
type decimal<[<Measure>] 'U>
type int<[<Measure>] 'U>
type sbyte<[<Measure>] 'U>
type int16<[<Measure>] 'U>
type int64<[<Measure>] 'U>
```

For the other types you can define your own.

For the numeric types, you can write your `new` function with `LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure` etc. which are actually slightly faster for floats.  I think recently the other numeric types have been optimised so that multiplication by 1 is done all at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It is much appreciated. I will go this route and define measure types for the types I need that are not in the spec.  It would be nice if compile time "tagging" of domain types would be something better integrated with the language itself.