# In F#, is there a way to define a type-checked alias for a primitive type?

Tags: f#

I want to define types that happen to be backed by the same type (say, `FirstName` and `LastName`, which are both `string`s), but I want them to be type-checked so that I cannot mix-and-match them by mistake:

```
> type FirstName = string;;
type FirstName = string

> type LastName = string;;
type LastName = string

> let n : FirstName = "John";;
val n : FirstName = "John"

//I wish this were caught:
> let l : LastName = n;;
val l : LastName = "John"
```

Is there a way to do this in F#, short of defining a record type or somesuch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a single-case discriminated union:

```
type FirstName =
    | FirstName of string

type LastName =
    | LastName of string

let n = FirstName "John"
let l: LastName = n // error
```

More information on how these can be used can be found in a blog post [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/).

Answer (score 3):

I believe Units of measure can be used on strings so you should be able to do this

```
[<Measure>]
type FirstName

[<Measure>]
type LastName

let n = "John"<Firstname>
let l:string<LastName> = n
```

and that will throw an error.  [Here is the MSDN Documentation of Units of Measure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx)

Comment: In theory, it might be a good idea. Three years ago I asked [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417150/compile-time-constraints-for-strings-in-f-similar-to-units-of-measure-is-it) about how to manage those UoM, but the question still remains effectively unanswered.

Comment: the thing about UoM's is they are a compiler feature in F# they are stripped from the compiled assembly.  The above code will throw an error on compile, but in the assembly n and l are simply strings.  So they can be accessed by any .Net assembly as strings,